Story in an early 90's Horror Anthology re: demons in basement of new house
I've been trying to track down this Horror Anthology book, or the story. I believe I read it in summer of '92.  It involves a brother and sister whose family move to a new house. Shortly after the kids are haunted by evil voices at night, and the see creepy little shadows.
These things are trying to lure them into the basement. The kids eventually trick another kid from down the block into going in their basement.  He emerges later with a terrified look on his face, and walks past them saying nothing.  They notice his shadow as he walks home, and it resembles the shadow of one of the creepy things that were bothering them.
I believe the author was a woman, possibly Lisa Tuttle?

That sounds very familiar... I could have sworn we had someone asking about that before, complete with the shadow detail.

OK thank you Fuzzy!  I will keep searching...
